# Dragging and pressing buttons - android?

Tags: android, multi-touch, ontouchlistener

I have several buttons and I would like to press on one of them and drag through another presing them. Could you tell me which MotionEvent or another functionality should I use. I'm using onTouchListener.

There is an image where you can see what I want to do (first ACTION_DOWN on 1st button and drag through 2nd-7th buttons still pressing the screen) and finally press every white buttons:![enter image description here][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNfvT.png

Below is my onTouch button code:

`button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getAction())
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        soundIDs[0] = sound.play(R.raw.sample1);
                        button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_clicked);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        sound.stop(soundIDs[0]);
                        button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white);
                        break;
                }
        return false;
        }
    });`